# How to select Kendo dropdown in selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm beginner in selenium web driver. I'm unable to select the kendo dropdown

Here is my code:

```
Select profcat = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/span/span/span[1]")));
profcat.selectByIndex(2);
```

```
<div unselectable="on" style="overflow: auto; position: relative; height: auto;">
   <ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="ddlCategoryTy_listbox" aria-live="polite" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox">
      <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" data-offset-index="0" id="f3776f55-02cc-45e9-9dd1-b32f24d457bd">Select</li>
      <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="1">Room</li>
      <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="2">Health Club</li>
      <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="3">Laundry</li>
      <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="4">Recreational Activities</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 2):

To select an item from the dropdown list, you will need to write an XPath to query on the text of the element you wish to select. I would also invoke `WebDriverWait` on the option you wish to click to account for any delayed loading time of the dropdown options:

```
// expand the dropdown -- click on the div, may need to click something else
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[ul[@id='ddlCategoryTy_listbox']]")).click()

// wait on an option to exist
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
optionToClick = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[text()='Health Club']")));

// click the option
optionToClick.click();
```

You will need to import `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions` and `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait` for this to work.

The above code clicks the `div` element to expand the dropdown, then select the option 'Health Club' using an XPath which queries on `li` text. You may need to update the selector used to expand the dropdown -- based on the HTML you provided, I cannot tell which element is meant to open the dropdown to display the options.

Comment: @MurugesanK glad to see it worked for you. Feel free to mark this post as the answer to your problem so other users can see that it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI doesn't have usual drop-downs. So your code will not work with it. You need to use next algorithm:

1. Click on button to open drop-down.
2. Wait for present of element, which contains list of values in drop-down (I was using debug in chrome to get this element).
3. Iterate in the list of values which appeared and click on the one, which you need.

I am using such algorithm to work with such kind of drop-downs.

Answer (score 0):

C# version use LINQ in Until Method.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xpathToDropDownList")).Click();
        
var ddlOption = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        .Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[contains(.,'Health Club')]")));
ddlOption.Click();
```